# how can I make this query show distinct model_nbr

Tags: sql, oracle

question about a join.

I have this query where I am joining stuff from three tables.

My question is when I got the result set 
Model A comes up twice there I was only expecting one row with Model A.

I want to show model A with 18 beeps only. But also want to show Model B with the 0 beeps as well.

How can I do this?  Am I not doing the join correctly?..

query:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
    TO_CHAR(C.KR_DATE,'YYYY/MM/DD') AS K_Date,
    A.OUT_FIELD1 AS MODEL_NBR, 
    A.IN_FIELD1 AS LOCATIONS,    
    sum(schemaJoe.FUNC_GET_LINE_TOUCHES(C.ORG, B.DELIV_ID, B.DELIV_DTL_NUM)) AS BEEPS     
FROM 
    schemaJoe.TABLE_A A, schemaJoe.TABLE_B B,  schemaJoe.TABLE_C C
    WHERE A.ORG = 'JOE'
    AND A.REF_TYPE = 'JOES_MODEL'
    AND A.ORG = B.ORG  (+) 
    AND A.OUT_FIELD1 = B.PART_NBR (+) 
    AND B.DELIVERY_ID = C.DELIVERY_ID (+) 
    AND C.CALC_REQUEST_DATE (+)  BETWEEN TO_DATE('7/30/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('8/30/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY') 
    AND B.LINE_STATUS (+) IN ( 'CREATED','OPEN','PROECSSING')  
GROUP BY 
    C.KR_DATE,
    A.OUT_FIELD1,
    A.IN_FIELD1,
    C.ORG,
    B.DELIVERY_ID,
    B.DELIV_LANE  
ORDER BY  
    K_Date ASC,BEEPS DESC,MODEL_NBR ASC,LOCATIONS ASC
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Showing the result is not useful without showing the data you're querying. Please post input sample data + actual vs. expected results.  Also, don't be surprised if you get some negative feedback regarding the use of Oracle's legacy left join syntax...

Comment: In "group by" more fields than in "select". select all fields from group by, and will understand the problem

Comment: @Mike - that my was my initial thought, but if it was only that the K_DATE would be set for the second result too. I think.

Comment: @AlexPoole I think the second K_DATE was selected by query and supressed client, when displayed on the screen. Or maybe you're right, and it is NULL

Comment: I'll try to take a snapshot of the sample data .. But basically what it is is that there is another model in Table B which has a K_Date (from table C) that falls outside of the range 7/30 - 8/31 ..

Comment: Could you please build the tables and fill it with sample data by using  sqlfiddle.com to check how to solve this issue

Comment: @psj01 - that sounds like that extra result should be there then. The sum for no date (in range) is zero. What is your logic for excluding it? You could possibly do it with a union but depends what the rules and logic really are.